# Excel: Automatically detect if value is lower or higher

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to have an excel sheet for staff with the following info

```
Name | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week 4 | Drop?
```

Info will be like

```
Mike | 100 | 80 | 90 | 100 | 90 | Yes
```

I want the last cell to tell me if the cell to the left, is lower than the cell to the left of that. But each week I will add a new week in. So dynamically always need the "drop" column to read the left two cells and tell me if the most recent one has dropped in value???

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Máté's solution is right. But you could also just copy the drop column to the column right of it, and change the first drop column into your new week. The drop column could have a simple formula as:

```
=IF(H14<G14;"Yes";"No")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`OFFSET()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) to make reference not affected by column inserts:

`=OFFSET(F2,0,-1)<OFFSET(F2,0,-2)`

[image]